# Pandas taking values in columns order

Tags: python, pandas

Given this df:

```
Name  i   j   k   
A     1   0   3
B     0   5   4   
C     0   0   4
D     0       5
```

My goal is to add in a column "Final" that takes value in an order of i j k:

```
Name  i   j   k     Final
A     1   0   3     1      
B     0   5   4     5 
C     0   0   4     4
D     0       5            <-- this one is tricky.  We do count the null for j column here.
```

Here is my attempt:  df['Final'] = df[['i', 'j', 'k'].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].  This doesn't work since it always takes the value of column 1.  Any help would be appreciated.  :)

Many thanks!

Comment: what you mean takes value in an order of i j k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df['Final']=df[['i', 'j', 'k']].mask((df=='')|(df==0)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0][(df!='').all(1)]
df
Out[1290]: 
  Name  i  j  k  Final
0    A  1  0  3    1.0
1    B  0  5  4    5.0
2    C  0  0  4    4.0
3    D  0     5    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

If by "taking values in column order", you mean "taking the first non-zero value in each row, or zero if all values are zero", you could use `DataFrame.lookup` after doing a boolean comparison:

```
In [113]: df["final"] = df.lookup(df.index,(df[["i","j","k"]] != 0).idxmax(axis=1))

In [114]: df
Out[114]: 
  Name  i    j  k  final
0    A  1  0.0  3    1.0
1    B  0  5.0  4    5.0
2    C  0  0.0  4    4.0
3    D  0  NaN  5    NaN
```

where first we compare everything with zero:

```
In [115]: df[["i","j","k"]] != 0
Out[115]: 
       i      j     k
0   True  False  True
1  False   True  True
2  False  False  True
3  False   True  True
```

and then we use `idxmax` to find the first True (or the first False if you have a row of zeroes):

```
In [116]: (df[["i","j","k"]] != 0).idxmax(axis=1)
Out[116]: 
0    i
1    j
2    k
3    j
dtype: object
```

Comment: appreciate the details! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas.Series.nonzero](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nonzero.html) the solution can be expressed succicntly.

```
df['Final'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.nonzero()[0][0]], axis=1)
```

How this works:

`nonzero()` returns the indices of elements that are not zero (and will match np.nan as well).

We take the first index location and return the value at that location to construct the `Final` Column.

We apply this on the dataframe using `axis=1` to apply it row by row.

A benefit of this approach is that it does not depend on naming individual columns `['i', 'j', 'k']`